# Scraping issues in Linkedin Sales Navigator

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape details of a few companies and their leads from the Linkedin Sales Navigator. To login, I have created a textfile named config.txt which has the username and password. The problem is that, It logins successfully, only to display another login page.

So, For eg: If I login through https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/rm/sign-in-another-account it logins successfully but then straightaway gives me another login page like: https://www.linkedin.com/sales/login

If I repeat the process for the 2nd url, then ideally it should give me the homepage of salesnavigator, but it again gives me the same page ie. https://www.linkedin.com/sales/login

Here's my code for the same:

```
def linkedin_scraper():
    print("Started Successfully.")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/rm/sign-in-another-account')
    file = open('config.txt')
    lines = file.readlines()
    username = lines[0]
    password = lines[1]

    time.sleep(1)
    usernameID = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
    usernameID.send_keys(username)
    time.sleep(1)

    passwordID = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
    passwordID.send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(1)

    browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/company?geoIncluded=102713980&industryIncluded=106%2C45&jobOpportunities=JO1')
    time.sleep(1)

    #maximizing window
    browser.maximize_window()
    # rest of code
```

Where is it exactly failing? I have no idea why is it happening so. Please let me  know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I reckon you need to press the login button after you've entered your username and password :)

Comment: Previosuly, without even pressing the login button I was able to login, but now if I include the login button, then I get a Checkpoint page which has some type of puzzle. @Ben

Comment: LinkedIn probably uses a captcha to stop bots, which unfortunately for you, is exactly what you've got. You can either solve the puzzle manually, or use the API that microsoft provides: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/ to get your data, rather than scraping webpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Linkedin Login Code**

As [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6857416/ben) said in the comment that Linkedin uses bot detector and for the same reason you are unable to login. For this reason you have used some additional chrome options.

The following code snippet will solve your problem

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

email = ""
password = ""
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")  WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#session_key")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#session_key').send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#session_password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > main > section.section.section--hero > div.sign-in-form-container > form > button").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "global-nav")))
print("Login Successful.")
```

Comment: Will suggest to change your question title to 'linkedin login issue' etc. so that others can get help too :)

Comment: Any options for Firefox @Sharyar?